# Rails 4 NOT updating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, nested-form-for

**Issue:** Instead of *updating* nested attributes, they are being *created* on top of the existing nested attributes when I hit the `#update` action of the associated `features_controller.rb`

**Likely Cause:** I think the problem lies in my lack of understanding in Rails' `form_for`. I think the breakdown is in my views, how I render the persisting nested attributes, and/or **how I fail to specify the nested attribute's id, causing it to simply create a new one**

**feature.rb**

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :scenarios
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scenarios,
    allow_destroy: true,
    reject_if: :all_blank
  ...
end
```

**features_controller.rb**

```
def update
  ...
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @feature = Feature.find(params[:id])

  if @feature.update_attributes(feature_params)
    # checking feature_params looks good...
    # feature_params['scenarios'] => { <correct object hash> }

    redirect_to project
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

...

private
def feature_params
  params.require(:feature).permit(:title, :narrative, :price, :eta, scenarios_attributes[:description, :_destroy])
end
```

**_form.html.haml (simplified)**

```
= form_for [@project, @feature] do |f|
  ...
  - if @feature.new_record? -# if we are creating new feature
    = f.fields_for :scenarios, @feature.scenarios.build do |builder|
      = builder.label :description, "Scenario"
      = builder.text_area :description, rows: "3", autocomplete: "off"

  - else -# if we are editing an existing feature
    = f.fields_for :scenarios do |builder|
      = builder.label :description, "Scenario"
      = builder.text_area :description, rows: "3", autocomplete: "off"
```

I'm sure there's a nicer way to achieve the `if @feature.new_record?` check. I'm also using a few Javascript hooks to create dynamic nested attribute forms (which I've left out), heavily influenced by [Railscast #196 Nested Model Form (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=asciicast)

I would love a really nice *Rails-y* implementation of dealing with these sorts of nested forms.

Comment: Would adding `:id` to the `:scenario_attributes` portion of your `feature_params` method fix it? You only have the description field and the ability to allow a destroy.

Comment: yes, that's exactly it!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try adding `:id` to the `:scenario_attributes` portion of your `feature_params` method. You only have the description field and the ability to allow a destroy.

```
def feature_params
  # added => before nested attributes
  params.require(:feature).permit(:id, :title, :narrative, :price, :eta, scenarios_attributes => [:id, :description, :_destroy])
end
```

As @vinodadhikary suggested, you no longer need to check if feature is a new record, since Rails, specifically using the `form_for` method, will do that for you.

**Update:**

You don't need to define `if @feature.new_record? ... else` in your form.  It will be taken care by Rails when you use `form_for`.  Rails checks if the action is going to be `create` or `update` based on `object.persisted?`, so, you can update your form to:

```
= form_for [@project, @feature] do |f|
  ...
  = f.fields_for :scenarios, @feature.scenarios.build do |builder|
    = builder.label :description, "Scenario"
    = builder.text_area :description, rows: "3", autocomplete: "off"
```

Comment: I would also suggest updating the form code, checking `feature.new_record?` is not necessary as `form_for` handles that itself.

Comment: You're more informed about the problem than I am, do you want to answer it? I mean that in a sincere manner :)

Comment: thanks guys, this is helpful information, i figured out the need for an `:id` in the strong parameter definition soon after I wrote this question. thanks also for the additional info on `form_for`, i'll attempt DRYing up my form :)

Comment: Is it safe to allow the user to set the id?

Comment: @Philip7899 Very good question. That seems like a potentially serious security hole.

Comment: @Philip7899 the id is only used to figure out which nested record must be updated... if none is passed it will try to create a new one

Answer (score 4):

As @Philip7899 mentioned as a comment in the accepted answer, allowing the user to set the `id` means that they *could* "steal" children records belonging to another user.

*However*, Rails `accepts_nested_attributes_for` actually checks the `id`  and raises:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
  Couldn't find Answer with ID=5 for Questionnaire with ID=5
```

Basically the ids are looked for in the children association (again, as said by @glampr).  Therefor, the child record belonging to another user is not found.

Ultimately, **401** is the response status (unlike the usual 404 from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`)

Follows some code I used to test the behaviour.

```
let :params do
  {
    id: questionnaire.id,
    questionnaire: {
      participation_id: participation.id,
      answers_attributes: answers_attributes
    }
  }
end

let :evil_params do
  params.tap do |params|
    params[:questionnaire][:answers_attributes]['0']['id'] = another_participant_s_answer.id.to_s
  end
end

it "doesn't mess with other people's answers" do
  old_value = another_participant_s_answer.value

  put :update, evil_params

  expect(another_participant_s_answer.reload.value).to eq(old_value) # pass
  expect(response.status).to eq(401) # pass
end
```

**In conclusion**, adding the `id` to the permitted params as stated above is correct and *safe*.

Fascinating Rails.

Comment: How to do it nicely if there are several nested_attributes possible? Let's assume there are comments associated with *questionnaire*. Do I just assign *id* to all possible nested parameters? It seems like an overkill. In my case I have a few 1:1 with nested records existing for only one specific model per record. Think fancy inheritance.

Comment: In my personal experience, if it gets too complicated, you've better move away from nested attributes and switch to a form object. This is a good resource http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: Good read! I ended up with `p.each_pair {|k,v| v[:id]=o.id if k.end_with?('_attributes')}` for now as I have 1:1 relation, where *p* is parent params and *o* is a parent object.