# Rails 4 - accept_nested_parameters_for does not update, but will create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In an attempt to use accept_nested_parameters_for I've run into an issue where I am unable to update my nested records. I've done quite a bit of research, but I'm quite certain that my problem cannot be solved with these other answers. Relevant research:

[Rails 4 deleting nested attributes, works on create but not on edit/update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584816/rails-4-deleting-nested-attributes-works-on-create-but-not-on-edit-update)

[Ruby on Rails - Edit/Update creating new records instead of updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901348/ruby-on-rails-edit-update-creating-new-records-instead-of-updating)

[Rails 4 NOT updating nested attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686189/rails-4-not-updating-nested-attributes)

All of the above answers suggest passing :id along with my other nested parameters, something that I'm already doing. Interestingly, I was able to get this to work on another project in the past, but cannot seem to get to this to work despite it being nearly identical.

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_event_types
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_event_types
    ...
end

class UserEventType < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      ...
end
```

Controller:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    ...
end

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:first_name, :last_name, :phone, user_event_types_attributes: [:id, :sms, :application, :email])
end
```

And the params sent to the controller:

```
{
    "utf8"=>"✓", 
    "authenticity_token"=>"...", 
    "user"=>{
    "email"=>"email", 
    "first_name"=>"Some", 
    "last_name"=>"Body", 
    "phone"=>"5555555555", 
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
    "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
    "user_event_types_attributes"=>{
       "0"=>{
           "application"=>"1", 
           "sms"=>"0", 
           "email"=>"0", 
           "id"=>"3"
       }, 
       "1"=>{
           "application"=>"1", 
           "sms"=>"1", 
           "email"=>"0", 
           "id"=>"4"}
      }
   }, 
  "id"=>"3"
}
```

By removing :id from user_event_types_attributes, I can get the controller to create new records, but it simply refuses to edit the existing ones. Instead, it just queries for the event_types

`SELECT "user_event_types".* FROM "user_event_types" WHERE "user_event_types"."user_id" = 3 AND "user_event_types"."id" IN (3, 4)`

but does nothing with the result!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did some attributes of user event types change indeed? Because if they aren't changed there won't be db request

Comment: @user3309314 no, the only statements executed where SELECTs. If the other params were changed (first_name for example) changed then those would be updated, but user_event_types would never be updated.

Comment: I mean are user_event_types updated when you change application or sms for example?

Comment: @user3309314 no, they are never updated despite there being a change that needs to reflected in the database.

Comment: Maybe `@user.update_attributes!(user_params)` will throw some exception what'll help to find out what's going on.

Comment: @user3309314 unfortunately, there aren't any exceptions being thrown! This really boggles my mind...